# why does it take long for the bash prompt to return on high system load

Tags: bash, prompt, load

When my server experiences high load and I run a command, there is a long delay after the command has finished before I get the prompt again. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Why is anything slow when there's high load? It's a game of chase the bottleneck. There's no magic bullet answer.

Comment: I mean it literally takes minutes to print the prompt. The actual command has finished executing (e.g. a cat printed the last line). Is this then the context switch before the shell gets to run again? That would be surprising.

Comment: My guess is that your terminal's nice level is outranked by more demanding processes, so it cannot compete for CPU and has to wait a little longer for attention.

Comment: How high of a load are we talking here? can you add some CPU averages for us?

Comment: Are you sure it's finished? Have you traced it to be certain that it has exited and returned control to the shell? There are about a million things that it *could* be, ranging from software to hardware.

Comment: load levels shown by uptime easily go up to 60 for 10 minutes. I have not straced the shell, but that would of course help to determine when the command finished and what ev. happens afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Something slow is running before each prompt, through the `PROMPT_COMMAND` mechanism. In my case, [this](https://github.com/rupa/j).